# Is the file upload size in struts2 on a per user session basis?

Tags: file-upload, web-applications, upload, struts2

struts2 is being used in a web application. Multiple users can login into this application at any given time. Each user has the option to upload a file from the web session that they are logged into and are using. 
In struts2, the file upload size can be set. Is this limit enforced on a per user's session? or is it for the entire web application usage?

Comment: It's unclear which file upload size do you mean. Every application has it's own logic that defines the rules you can or cannot do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the maximum file upload size is set at the application level.